# htaccess rewriterule to specific laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, lumen, laravel-5.8

I have two different htacces. One on the root of project and the other one on a subfolder:

root

- .htaccess
- api

  - .htaccess

I need to rewrite rule to a specific route on api folder.
In the first .htaccess (inside root) I wrote (but it doesn't works):

```
RewriteRule "^sitemap\.xml" "/api/aaa/bbb" [L,QSA]
```

where

```
/api/aaa/bbb
```

is a public route (https://myhost.com/api/aaa/bbb) and api folder has the *public* subfolder with *index.php*

So I need to have the response of /api/aaa/bbb with the url https://myhost.com/sitemap.xml

How can I rewriterule (not redirect 301) to this specific laravel folder

Comment: You need to do this in Laravel itself, not `.htaccess`, unless there is a mechanism in Laravel that allows you to pass the desired URL via a URL parameter or path-info? Laravel is unaware of the intermediary rewrite to `/api/aaa/bbb`, which is ultimately rewritten to `index.php` (the Laravel front-controller). Laravel sees only the requested URL, ie. `/sitemap.xml`. (If Laravel did check for the rewritten URL - it's technically possible to some degree - it would always see `index.php` - since that is always the last rewrite.)

Comment: @MrWhite you're right. I've added a route with the specific path (/sitemap.xml) and called relative controller and method.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do not use .htaccess. Use the exactly path into the route

```
$router->get('sitemap.xml', 'MyController@myMethod');
```

Now you can call https://myhost.com/sitemap.xml
and it will load **MyController@myMethod**